# React, after expiring JWT token, moving to login page

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-dom

This useEffect is in the part of the head in my website so whenever the website refresh, it authenticates whether the token expires or not.
and this component is routed but when the token expired, history.push is not working.
Error message: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
except for this, history.push in other pages are working well.
I can't figure what it's the problem.

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
let history = useHistory();
useEffect(() => {
        if (isLoggedIn) {
            dispatch(loginValid());
            history.push('/login');
        }
    }, [])
```

action

```
export const loginValid = () => (dispatch) => {
    return AuthService.loginValid()
        .then((data) => {
            dispatch({
                type: SET_MESSAGE,
                payload: data.message,
            });
            return Promise.resolve();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            alert(v_session_expired);
            dispatch(logout());
            const message =
                (error.response &&
                    error.response.data &&
                    error.response.data.message) ||
                error.message ||
                error.toString();
            dispatch({
                type: LOGOUT
            });
            dispatch({
                type: SET_MESSAGE,
                payload: message,
            });
            return Promise.reject();
        })
```

route

```
const Body = (props) => {

    return (
        <div>
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Head}></Route>
               </Switch>
            </Router>
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: import withRouter from react-router-dom and wrap it with app.js file

Comment: I tried that but I got a error: ×
Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <withRouter(Head) /> outside a <Router> I don't know what happens on that